# How to transform an affirmative sentence into a general question using Python Udapi?

Tags: python, nlp, cycle

I would like to trasnform some pretty simple affirmative sentences into general questions (the language of choise is Spanish). Consider the following example:

***Esto es muy difícil. -> Es esto muy difícil?***

So I just need to shift the position of subject and predicate (wherever they are).

Normally it can be done with the `shift_before_node()` method:

```
pron_node, aux_node = tree.descendants[0], tree.descendants[1]
aux_node.shift_before_node(pron_node)
```

However, if I want to automate the process (because subject and predicate will not always be in the same position) I need to create a cycle (See **The Problem** paragraph below) for each node of a tree, where it checks that if node's part of speech (`upos`) is a `PRON` or `PROPN`, and it is followed (not necessarily directly) by a node which is a `VERB` or `AUX`, it needs to shift the second node before the first one (like in the example above). But, I dont know how to implement it into cycle. Any suggestions?

Here is my code so far (done in Google Colab). I apologize for excluding some of the console text, otherwise it would be too lengthy:

**Request to UDPipe server**

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe/api/models")
info = response.json()
info

for key, data in info["models"].items():
    if "spanish" in key:
        print(key, data)

params = {"tokenizer": "", "tagger": "", "parser": "", "model": "spanish-gsd-ud-2.6-200830"}

text = "Esto es muy difícil."
params["data"] = text
response = requests.get("http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe/api/process", params)
json_response = response.json()

parse = json_response["result"]
print(parse)
```

**Output #1 (`print (parse)`):**

```
# generator = UDPipe 2, https://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe
# udpipe_model = spanish-gsd-ud-2.6-200830
# udpipe_model_licence = CC BY-NC-SA
# newdoc
# newpar
# sent_id = 1
# text = Esto es muy difícil.
1   Esto    este    PRON    _   Number=Sing|PronType=Dem    4   nsubj   _   _
2   es  ser AUX _   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin   4   cop _   _
3   muy mucho   ADV _   _   4   advmod  _   _
4   difícil difícil ADJ _   Number=Sing 0   root    _   SpaceAfter=No
5   .   .   PUNCT   _   _   4   punct   _   SpaceAfter=No
```

**Udapi Installation:**

```
!pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/udapi/udapi-python.git
import os
os.environ['PATH'] += ":" + os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], ".local/bin")

from udapi.block.read.conllu import Conllu
from udapi.core.document import Document
from udapi.block.write.textmodetrees import TextModeTrees

from io import StringIO
```

**Building a tree:**

In my understanding a `tree` is a variable of a built in Udapi class, which is a structured version of a `parse` variable, and which contains all the information about each word of a sentence - its order (`ord`), given form (`form`), initial form (`lemma`), part of speech (`upos`) and so on:

```
tree = Conllu(filehandle=StringIO(parse)).read_tree()
writer = TextModeTrees(attributes="ord,form,lemma,upos,feats,deprel", layout="align")
writer.process_tree(tree)
```

**Output #2 (`writer.process_tree(tree)`):**

```
# sent_id = 1
# text = Esto es muy difícil.
─┮                                                                                  
 │ ╭─╼ 1 Esto    este    PRON  Number=Sing|PronType=Dem                              nsubj
 │ ┢─╼ 2 es      ser     AUX   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin cop
 │ ┢─╼ 3 muy     mucho   ADV   _                                                     advmod
 ╰─┾   4 difícil difícil ADJ   Number=Sing                                           root
   ╰─╼ 5 .       .       PUNCT _                                                     punct
```

It is also possible to print out all the dependents for each node of a given tree. As already correctly noted in the comments, `tree.descendants` consists of a list of nodes:

```
for node in tree.descendants:
    print(f"{node.ord}:{node.form}")
    left_children = node.children(preceding_only=True)
    if len(left_children) > 0:
        print("Left dependents:", end=" ")
        for child in left_children:
            print(f"{child.ord}:{child.form}", end=" ")
        print("")
    right_children = node.children(following_only=True)
    if len(right_children) > 0:
        print("Right dependents:", end=" ")
        for child in right_children:
            print(f"{child.ord}:{child.form}", end=" ")
        print("")
```

**Output #3:**

```
1:Esto
2:es
3:muy
4:difícil
Left dependents: 1:Esto 2:es 3:muy 
Right dependents: 5:. 
5:.
```

**The problem (beginning of a cycle):**

```
for node in tree.descendants:
  if node.upos == "VERB" or node.upos == "AUX":
```

**UPDATE 1**

So, I`ve come to the first somewhat complete version of a needed cycle and now it looks like this:

```
for i, curr_node in enumerate(nodes[1:], 1):
  prev_node = nodes[i-1]
  if (prev_node.upos == "PRON" or prev_node.upos == "PROPN") and (curr_node.upos == "VERB" or curr_node.upos == "AUX"):
    curr_node.shift_before_node(prev_node)
```

But now I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-a967bbd730fe> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11 for i, curr_node in enumerate(nodes[1:], 1):
     12   prev_node = nodes[i-1]
     13   if (prev_node.upos == "PRON" or prev_node.upos == "PROPN") and (curr_node.upos == "VERB" or curr_node.upos == "AUX"):

NameError: name 'nodes' is not defined
```

**UPDATE 2**

I tried defining `nodes` like that:

```
nodes = tree.descendants
```

And now my cycle compiles at least, but it still didn't do anything with the structure of a given sentence:

```
nodes = tree.descendants
for i, curr_node in enumerate(nodes[1:], 1):
  prev_node = nodes[i-1]
  if (prev_node.upos == "PRON" or prev_node.upos == "PROPN") and (curr_node.upos == "VERB" or curr_node.upos == "AUX"):
    curr_node.shift_before_node(prev_node)
```

Checking the `tree`:

```
tree = Conllu(filehandle=StringIO(parse)).read_tree()
writer = TextModeTrees(attributes="ord,form,lemma,upos,feats,deprel", layout="align")
writer.process_tree(tree)
# sent_id = 1
# text = Esto es muy difícil.
─┮                                                                                  
 │ ╭─╼ 1 Esto    este    PRON  Number=Sing|PronType=Dem                              nsubj
 │ ┢─╼ 2 es      ser     AUX   Mood=Ind|Number=Sing|Person=3|Tense=Pres|VerbForm=Fin cop
 │ ┢─╼ 3 muy     mucho   ADV   _                                                     advmod
 ╰─┾   4 difícil difícil ADJ   Number=Sing                                           root
   ╰─╼ 5 .       .       PUNCT _
```

Nothing changed.

**UPDATE 3**

I've also tried to check if the cycle swaps subject and predicate back again (2nd time), making the sentence look like the original one, but I guess it's not the case, becuase even if I comment the `break` part, `flag` has increased by 1 only:

```
nodes = tree.descendants
flag = 1
for i, curr_node in enumerate(nodes[1:], 1):
  prev_node = nodes[i-1]
  if ((prev_node.upos == "PRON") or (prev_node.upos == "PROPN")) and ((curr_node.upos == "VERB") or (curr_node.upos == "AUX")):
    curr_node.shift_before_node(prev_node)
    flag = flag + 1
    # if flag == 2:
    #   break
print(flag)
```

Output

```
2
```

HOWEVER, it means, that the condition `if ((prev_node.upos == "PRON") or (prev_node.upos == "PROPN")) and ((curr_node.upos == "VERB") or (curr_node.upos == "AUX"))` was satisified.

Comment: You have not defined a variable named `nodes`, as indicated in the error message.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of defining this specific variable in that particular case? Im very sorry for being direct, but Im trying to work it out now and I'm still a bit clueless of how to do it so that the cycle will work correctly. I guess `nodes` must be a list which contains all the words of a given sentence?

Comment: You have not provided a lot of context, for instance what is the `tree` variable? From what you provide, I can guess that `tree.descendants` comprises a list of nodes.

Comment: @Carsten I`ve updated the question, I hope now everything will become a bit clearer!

Comment: I think I solved it! I`ll post the answer as soon, as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is one sentence per line in `affirm.txt` with affirmative Spanish sentences such as "*Esto es muy difícil.*" or "*Tus padres compraron esa casa de la que me hablaste.*".

As an alternative to using the UDPipe web service, we can parse the sentences locally (I slightly prefer the es_ancora model over es_gsd):

```py
import udapi
doc = udapi.Document('affirm.txt')
udapi.create_block('udpipe.Base', model_alias='es_ancora').apply_on_document(doc)
```

To make repeated experiments faster, we can now store the parsed trees to a CoNLL-U file using `doc.store_conllu('affirm.conllu')` and later load it using `doc = udapi.Document('affirm.conllu')`.

To draw the trees we can use the `doc.draw()` method (or even `tree.draw()`), which is a syntactic sugar that uses `TextModeTrees()` behind the scenes. So to compare the sentences before and after changing the word order, we can use:

```py
print("Original word order:")
doc.draw() # or doc.draw(attributes="ord,form,lemma,deprel,feats,misc")

for tree in doc.trees:
    process_tree(tree)

print("Question-like word order:")
doc.draw()
```

Now comes the main work - to implement the `process_tree()` subroutine. Note that

- We need to change the word order of the main clause only (e.g "*Tus padres compraron esa casa.*"), not any dependent clauses (e.g. "*de la que me hablaste*".) So we don't want to iterate over all nodes (`tree.descendants`), we just need to find the main predicate (usually a verb) and its subject.
- The subject does not need to be only PRON and PROPN, it can be NOUN or maybe just ADJ if the governing noun is omitted. So it is safer to just ask for `deprel=nsubj` (handling `csubj` is beyond the scope of this question).
- I don't speak Spanish, but I think the rule is not as simple as moving the verb before the subject (or moving the subject after the verb). At least, we need to distinguish transitive verbs (with objects) and copula constructions. Of course, even the solution below is not perfect. It is rather an example how to use Udapi.
- We should handle the nasty details like capitalization and spacing.

```py
def process_tree(tree):
    # Find the main predicate and its subject
    main_predicate = tree.children[0]
    nsubj = next((n for n in main_predicate.children if n.udeprel == 'nsubj'), None)
    if not nsubj:
        return

    # Move the subject
    # - after the auxiliary copula verb if present
    # - or after the last object if present
    # - or after the main predicate (verb)
    cop = next((n for n in main_predicate.children if n.udeprel == 'cop'), None)
    if cop:
        nsubj.shift_after_subtree(cop)
    else:
        objects = [n for n in main_predicate.children if n.udeprel in ('obj', 'iobj')]
        if objects:
            nsubj.shift_after_subtree(objects[-1])
        else:
            nsubj.shift_after_node(verb)

    # Fix the capitalization
    nsubj_start = nsubj.descendants(add_self=True)[0]
    if nsubj_start.lemma[0].islower() and nsubj_start.form[0].isupper():
        nsubj_start.form = nsubj_start.form.lower()
    tree.descendants[0].form = tree.descendants[0].form.capitalize()
    
    # Add a question mark (instead of fullstop)
    dots = [n for n in main_predicate.children if n.form == '.']
    if not dots:
        dots = [main_predicate.create_child(upos="PUNCT", deprel="punct")]
    dots[-1].form = '?'
    
    # Fix spacing
    dots[-1].prev_node.misc["SpaceAfter"] = "No"
    nsubj_start.prev_node.misc["SpaceAfter"] = ""

    # Recompute the string representation of the sentence
    tree.text = tree.compute_text()
```

The solution above uses Udapi as a library. An alternative would be to move the main code into a Udapi block called e.g. `MakeQuestions`:

```py
from udapi.core.block import Block

class MakeQuestions(Block):
   
    def process_tree(self, tree):
        # the rest is same as in the solution above
```

If we store this block in the current directory in file `makequestions.py`, we can call it from the command line in many ways:

```bash
# parse the affirmative sentences
cat affirm.txt | udapy -s \
   read.Sentences \
   udpipe.Base model_alias=es_ancora \
 > affirm.conllu

# visualize the output with TextModeTrees (-T)
cat affirm.conllu | udapy -T .MakeQuestions | less -R

# store the output in CoNLL-U
udapy -s .MakeQuestions < affirm.conllu > questions.conllu

# show just the plain-text sentences
udapy write.Sentences < questions.conllu > questions.txt

# visualize the differences in HTML
udapy -H \
 read.Conllu files=affirm.conllu zone=affirm \
 read.Conllu files=questions.conllu zone=questions \
 util.MarkDiff gold_zone=affirm attributes=form ignore_parent=1 \
> differences.html
```